# What is friendship affinity?

Tags: bravely-default

The Summoner class has one or two skills about increasing friendship affinity, and I've also seen one or two messages about affinity increases after summoning a Friend. What is are the benefit and effects of affinity, and what actions will increase it?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this site](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/729328-bravely-default/68255421), you can read that Ogogin and Matoda seem to have the answers for you.

It seems that

> Standing to the ingame tutorial, friendship only increase the strength of the attack executed. You can't summon a friend twice without street/spotpassing him again, unfortunately (it would have been great, but nothing).

And

> they'll only ever go past 9999 strength if the original sent attack was using Bravely Second in the first place"

Comment: That explains why I've got a friend with a listed damage of 17k - they must have used Bravely Second to get an extra attack in.